# ESXi + KVM-over-IP

Tags: vmware-esxi, keyboard-video-mouse

I have a server running ESXi and a KVM-over-IP switch.  I know traditionally SSH/RDP/VNC are used to access the virtual machines running on the ESXi server.  However, I was wondering if it is possible to use the KVM-over-IP switch to access the different virtual machines running on the ESXi server?  I have very minimal KVM-over-IP experience so I don't even know where to begin looking.

If it makes a difference, the KVM-over-IP switch is a Dominion KX II.

Comment: There's no "physical" console, keyboard or mouse connections on a virtual machine. You can connect to the hypervisor console but you can't connect to the "console" of a virtual machine via a KVM, IP or otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't access VMs directly from the ESXi console. You can get the web address of its web client, which is how you'll need to manage your virtual machines, if you don't already have a vSphere client installed on your computer.

Comment: You'll need vCenter to use a web client.  With stand alone ESX hosts you cannot use a web client to manage the VMs.  Otherwise use the vSphere Client which must be installed.

Comment: What he means is that the vSphere client can be downloaded from the ESXi by browsing it in HTTP which leads to a welcome page with a download link.